# ChartJs: remove line between two points

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I have inherited a line chart made with chartjs from another developer. My client asked me to not show a line between the last two data points. Can this be done with chartjs? I have seen documentation to make a part of the line dotted, but to remove it completely. Only when there is a `NaN` number in between, but that would mean an additonal point in my line, which I cannot do as it would mess up the data.

For some reason, I also can't seem to get the segments working in typescript. When I try to add it to the `ChartDataSets` interface, I get the error that `segments` are not part of this interface.

The code I use for the dataset right now:

```
const chartDataSet: ChartDataSets = {
    data,
    label,
    borderWidth: 1,
    fill: false, // do not fill surface under line
    lineTension: 0, // set to 0 to use straight lines between points. Higher values show interpolated values
    borderDash: [0], // set to [0] for solid link, [x,y] to have dashes with length x and space with length y
    borderColor: color,
    pointBorderColor: color,
    pointBackgroundColor: color,
    pointRadius: 2
};
```

Comment: You can remove the last data from `data`. If you dont want that! 
Can you show the full error message `segment` interface? 
[refer here](https://pub.dev/documentation/chartjs/latest/chart.js/ChartDataSets-class.html) for more details on `ChartDataSets`.

Comment: If it were only that easy.  They want the data point, they don't want the line between the last two data points.

Comment: Btw, the error I'm getting is `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'segment' does not exist in type 'ChartDataSets'.`

Comment: I've opened this and the technical complexity is too specific for my scenario. Besides, the business does not need this anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the segments for this like so:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  ngOnInit() {
    const chart = new Chart("tt", {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: ["Red", "blue", "Pink", "Grey"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "ff",
            data: [5, 4, 2, 6],
            pointBorderColor: "red",
            pointBackgroundColor: "red",
            segment: {
              borderColor: (ctx) =>
                ctx.p1DataIndex !==
                chart.data.datasets[ctx.datasetIndex].data.length - 1
                  ? "red"
                  : "transparent"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {}
    });
  }
}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-shockley-w3swt?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I don't see any line. It's just an empty grid.  Also, there is no `Chart` defined in `ngOnInit`. There is a canvas with the `baseChart` directive. The datasets are dynamically added and updated as I can apply filters to the dataset and get more data (it's a time series and I can set the start and end date) or add/remove datasets on the fly (selectable dropdown). So this static approach won't work. Thanks for the information though, I appreciate the help. 

Comment: Lines show fine for me, might need to reload the internal browser, also you can just replace the chart by your normal dataset variable

Comment: Ok, my adblocker stopped something that showed the lines. My bad. But when I add the segment property to my code above (which is used to add a line to the chart), I get the following error: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'segment' does not exist in type 'ChartDataSets'`. Before you say, just remove the type. The lead frontend dev requires that all functions have types, `any` is not allowed. Git commit hook blocks committing something with the type `any`.

Comment: As you can see in my example which is also using typescript it doesnt throw the error so only thing I can imagine without you providing a working example is that you are not using the latest version of the lib, if you are using the latest version you might have `@types/chart.js` installed which you need to uninstall since the latest version has build in typing

Comment: You are right, I'm not using the latest version. I also can't update as there is a dependency on `ng2-charts` that requires version 2.9.3. I can't update to v3.x.x without breaking other parts of the site. This does kind of solve it for me. The business will have to choose how badly they want this change. Do we upgrade the whole site or just keep it as is.

Comment: please next time put these kind of details in your question so you dont waste time since this solution does not work for V2, although you can install the `next` branch of the ng2-charts which is based on chart.js v3

Comment: 'transparent' -> seems so obvious now. I had the exact same issue and this one solved it. Thanks